# SSRS Expression Issue,problems with a ) or a ,

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

My SQL Statement:

```
=IIF
(
  IIF(
   SUM(Fields!EstUnits.Value) <= 0,
   0,
   Sum(Fields!JTDUnits.Value) / 
   IIF
   (
     Sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value)=0,
     1, 
     Sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value)
   )
  )<=0,
  Sum(Fields!PeriodCost.Value) + Sum(Fields!EstCost.Value),
  IIF
  (
    IIF
    (
      SUM(Fields!EstUnits.Value) <= 0,
      0,
      Sum(Fields!JTDUnits.Value) / 
      IIF
      (
        Sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value)
      )
    )>0.25,
    Sum(Fields!JTDCost.Value)/ Sum(Fields!EstCost.Value),
    Sum(Fields!EstCost.Value)
  )
)
```

Getting error message:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.
```

I know its a ) or , but I have been trying to get this right for hours and I would love some extra eyes on this.
The statement should be evaluating if % is <= zero, than add two columns together, else if % is more than 25%, than divide column by %, else = column

Comment: I did some formatting on you expression, and it looks good to me. I think you should take parts out of it by replacing it by a simple number, and try them out if it works or not. That way you'll find the offending section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I dissolve the expression it comes to this (I replaced a value always with `4` and a condition with `b`):

```
=IIF(4)<=0,4,4)
```

You have to check yourself, because I dont really know how to correct this expression based on your outcome:

```
=IIF(
  IIF(
      b,
      0,
      4 / IIF(b,1, 4)
      ) <=0,
          4,
  IIF(
   IIF(
       b,
       0,
       4 / IIF(b,1,4)
       ) >0.25,
             4,
             4
     )
    )
```